# Cannot extract data from google calendar to spreadsheet by using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am trying to extract data from Google calendar to spreadsheet.

There seems to be no syntax error and the program says the extraction is complete. But I only get the message "Done" and I do not see any result on the spreadsheet.

The calendar has multiple events so it's not a problem of calendar.

Can somebody help me to figure out what is going on?  Thank you.

```
function getRoom2MonthEvent()
{
    var endDate = new Date();
    var myCals = CalendarApp.getCalendarById( 'example@gmail.com' );
    var myRow = 2
    var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startDate = new Date();


    startDate.setHours( 0 );
    startDate.setMinutes( 0 );
    startDate.setSeconds( 0 );
    startDate.setDate( 0 );

    endDate.setHours( 0 );
    endDate.setMinutes( 0 );
    endDate.setSeconds( 0 );
    endDate.setMonth( endDate.getMonth() + 1 );
    endDate.setDate( 1 );

    for ( i in myCals )
    {
        var myCals = myCals[ i ];
        var myEvents = myCal.getEvents(startDate, endDate);


        mySheet.getRange( myRow, 1 ).setValue( myCal.getName() );

        if ( myEvents.length > 0 )
        {
            for ( j = 0;
                  i < myEvents.length;
                  i++ )
            {
                var myEvent = myEvents[ i ];


                mySheet.getRange( myRow, 2 ).setValue( myEvent.getTitle() );
                mySheet.getRange( myRow, 3 ).setValue( myEvent.getStartTime() );
                mySheet.getRange( myRow, 4 ).setValue( myEvent.getEndTime() );
                myRow++;
            }
        }
    }

    Browser.msgBox( "Done" );
}
```

Comment: `getCalendarById` returns a single calendar object, so `for (i in myCals)` doesn't have anything to iterate over.

Comment: If anything it iterates over the property keys of the calendar. myEvents will be undefined and the script terminates.

Answer (score 0):

As Josh Dawson mentionned it, the CalendarApp.getCalendarById() method, your iteration as no point, unless you get data from multiple calendar.

You can use the [CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getDefaultCalendar()) or the [CalendarApp.getCalendarByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getCalendarsByName(String)) methods to get the exact calendar that you want. 
Otherwise, if you want to manipulate multiple calendar, you can use the [CalendarApp.getAllCalendars()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getAllCalendars()) method. In this case, you must be the owner or be subscribed to the calendar that you want to manipulate.

Hint: To avoid that you need to confirm when Browser.msgBox() method is use, you can use the [Spreadsheet.toast()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toast(String)) method instead, that will pop a message on the right bottom of the window.